# Selenium Webscraper Unbound local error in set [ ]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I inherited a bit of Python code and I have no background. I am getting unbound local error and is probably something really silly on my part.

---

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 372>()
    368     print('\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n')
    369 ##############################################################################
--> 372 main()

Input In [1], in main()
    319 Gender = p.getGender()
    320 StateRes = p.getStateRes()
--> 321 children = immunte(Fname, Lname, DOB, Gender, driver)
    323 if children == []:
    324     not_found += 1

Input In [1], in immunte(Fname, Lname, DOB, Gender, driver)
    204 except WebDriverException:
    205     al = []
--> 207 return  al

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'al' referenced before assignment
```

I have looked at this for a few days now and I can't seem to find an answer to this problem even though it is likely simple. It seems a solution to this error is a global keyword somewhere but I am not sure if this applies here as every time I tried to apply global to al =  [] i got an error or same result.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
# Imports
import csv
import datetime
import os
import os.path
import time

import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse
from pandas import DataFrame
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import (NoSuchElementException,
                                        WebDriverException)
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
##############################################################################
# Classes


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, measYr, MEMID, MIDSK, fname, lname, LNMSFX, DRB, GDR, STRES, meas):
        self.measYr = measYr
        self.MEMID = MEMID
        self.MIDSK = MIDSK
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.LNMSFX = LNMSFX
        self.DRB = DRB
        self.GDR = GDR
        self.STRES = STRES
        self.meas = meas

    def GTMESYR(self):
        return self.measYr

    def GTMEMSKY(self):
        return self.MIDSK

    def GTMEMID(self):
        return self.MEMID

    def GTFSNM(self):
        return self.fname

    def GTLSNM(self):
        return self.lname

    def GTLSTNMSF(self):
        return self.LNMSFX

    def GTDRB(self):
        return self.DRB

    def GTGDR(self):
        return self.GDR

    def getStateRes(self):
        return self.STRES

    def getMeas(self):
        return self.meas

###############################################################################
# Function


def is_date(string, fuzzy=False):
    try:
        parse(string, fuzzy=fuzzy)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False


def immunte(Fname, Lname, DRB, GDR, driver):
    
    # work on  search button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edittesttest']").click()

    # work on 
    lastname = driver.find_element_by_id("LM")
    lastname.clear()
    lastname.send_keys(Lname)

    # work on 
    firstname = driver.find_element_by_id("FN")
    firstname.clear()
    firstname.send_keys(Fname)

    # work on 
    birthdate = driver.find_element_by_id("DRB")
    birthdate.clear()
    birthdate.send_keys(DRB)

    # work on advanced search button to input GDR
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='queryResultsForm']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/input").click()

        # work on GDR selection button
        obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("OSC"))
        if GDR == 'W':
            obj.select_by_index(2)
        elif GDR == 'S':
            obj.select_by_index(1)
        else:
            obj.select_by_index(3)

        # work on search button
        driver.find_element_by_name("cmdFindClient").click()

    

        # two scenarios could emerge as a search result: 1, not found 2, the  found
        if "No were found for the requested search criteria" in driver.find_element_by_id("queryResultsForm").text:
            al = [] 

        elif "the found" in driver.find_element_by_id("queryResultsForm").text:

            # work on button
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//*[@id='queryResultsForm']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/label").click()

            # work on pt button
            driver.find_element_by_id("redirect1").click()

            # work on getting rid of opt out  - header
            header = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("large")[1].text

            if "Access Restricted" in header:
                print(Fname+' '+Lname+' '+" Opt out")
                al = []

            elif "Information" in header:
                # find the first line
                first = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "//*[@id='container']/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]").text
                if (first == None):
                    al = []

                else:
                    even = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("evenRow")
                    odd = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("oddRow")
                    o = []
                    e = []

                    for value in odd:
                        o.append(value.text)
                    for value in even:
                        e.append(value.text)

                    length = len(o)
                    i = 0
                    al = []

                    # merge odd and even row together and remove the row marked with complete
                    while i < length:
                        al.append(e[i])
                        al.append(o[i])
                        i = i+1

                    # parse each row of information with a comma, add group name for row that are without one
                    for x in range(len(al)):
                        if is_date(al[x][1:10]):
                            al[x] = al[x].replace(' ', ',')
                            al[x] = al[x].replace(',of,', ' of ')
                            al[x] = group + ',' + al[x][2:]

                        else:
                            al[x] = al[x].replace(' ', ',')
                            al[x] = al[x].replace(',of,', ' of ')
                            g = al[x].split(',', 1)
                            group = g[0]
                        
        # work on returning to home page
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='headerMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        al = []

    except WebDriverException:
        al = []
    
    return  al



def main():
    # Welcome message and input info
    print('\nThis is the test.')
    print('You will be prompted to type .')
    print('If you need to exit the script and stop its process press \'CTRL\' + \'C\'.')
    file = input("\nEnter file name: ")
    user = input("\nEnter username: ")
    pw = input("\nEnter password: ")

    date = str(datetime.date.today())

    # output file
    fileOutputName = 'FILELIST' + \
        date.replace('-', '_') + '.csv'
    fileOutputNameNotFound = 'NOTFOUNDFILELIST' + \
        date.replace('-', '_') + '.csv'

    fileOutput = open(fileOutputName, 'w')
    fileOutputNotFound = open(fileOutputNameNotFound, 'w')

    fileOutput.write('MEAS_YR,MEMLFIDSK,MEMLFID,MEMB_FRST_NM,MEMLSTNM,' +
                     'DRB,GNDR,RSDNC_STATE,IMUN_RGSTRY_STATE,VCCN_GRP,VCCN_ADMN_DT,DOSE_SERIES,' +
                     'BRND_NM,DOSE_SIZE,RCTN\n')

    fileOutputNotFound.write('MEAS_YR,MEMLFIDSK,MEMLFID,MEMB_FRST_NM,MEMLSTNM,MEMB_SUFFIX,' +
                             'DRB,GNDR,RSDNC_STATE,IMUN_RGSTRY_STATE,VCCN_GRP,VCCN_ADMN_DT,DOSE_SERIES,' +
                             'BRND_NM,DOSE_SIZE,RCTN\n')

    # If the file exists
    try:
        os.path.isfile(file)
    except:
        print('File Not Found\n')

    df = pd.read_excel(file)

    # create array of People objects and member ID
    peopleArray = []
    memberIdArray = []
    df.dropna()
    total = len(df)
    not_found = 0
    found = 0

    # assign each record in the data frame into Person class
    for i in range(total):
        measYr = str(df.loc[i, "MEAS_YR"])
        MEMID = str(df.loc[i, "MEMLFID"])
        MIDSK = str(df.loc[i, "MEMLFIDSK"])
        fname = str(df.loc[i, "MEMLFID"])
        lname = str(df.loc[i, "MEMLSTNM"])
        
        inputDate = str(df.loc[i, "DRB"])
        # If date is null then assign an impossible date
        if not inputDate:
            DRB = '01/01/1900'
        if '-' in inputDate:
            DRB = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                inputDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        else:
            DRB = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                str(df.loc[i, "DRB"]), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        GDR = str(df.loc[i, "GDR"])
        STRES = str(df.loc[i, "STATE_RES"])
        meas = str(df.loc[i, "MEAS"])

        p = Person(measYr, MEMID, MIDSK, fname, lname,
                   LNMSFX, DRB, GDR, STRES, meas)

        # append array
        m = df.loc[i, "MEMLFID"]

        if (m not in memberIdArray):
            peopleArray.append(p)

        memberIdArray.append(m)

    # work on setting up driver for md immunet - mac forward slash/windows double backward slash
    PATH = os.getcwd()+'\\'+'chromedriver'
    s = Service(PATH)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s)
    driver.get("https://www.wow2.pe.org/prd-IR/portalmanager.do")

    # work on login ID
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("userField")
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys(user)

    # work on password
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys(pw)

    # work on getting to home page - where loop will start
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id='loginButtonForm']/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input").click()

    for n in range(total):
        p = peopleArray[n]
        recordToWrite = ''
        print('Looking up: ' + str(n)+' ' +
              p.GTLSNM() + ', ' + p.GTFSNM())
        MeasYr = p.GTMESYR()
        MIDSK = p.GTMEMSKY()
        MEMID = p.GTMEMID()
        Fname = p.GTFSNM()
        Lname = p.GTLSNM()
        DRB = str(p.GTDRB())
        GDR = p.GTGDR()
        STRES = p.getStateRes()
        children = immunte(Fname, Lname, DRB, GDR, driver)

        if children == []:
            not_found += 1
            recordToWrite = MeasYr+','+MIDSK+','+MEMID+',' + Fname + \
                ','+Lname + ',' + ' ' + ','+DRB+','+GDR+','+STRES+','+'MD'
            fileOutputNotFound.write(recordToWrite + '\n')
        elif children != []:
            found += 1
            for x in range(len(children)):
                data_element = children[x].split(",")

                # if the admin date is not valid
                if is_date(data_element[1]) and is_date(data_element[3]):
                    children[x] = ''
                elif is_date(data_element[1]) and data_element[2] == 'NOT' and data_element[3] == 'VALID':
                    children[x] = ''
                elif is_date(data_element[1]) and is_date(data_element[3]) == False:
                    if data_element[5] != 'No':
                        data_element[4] = data_element[5]
                        data_element[5] = ''
                        children[x] = ','.join(data_element[0:6])
                    else:
                        data_element[5] = ''
                        children[x] = ','.join(data_element[0:6])
                else:
                    children[x] = ''

            for x in range(len(children)):
                if children[x] != '':
                    recordToWrite = MeasYr+','+MIDSK+','+MEMID+',' + \
                        Fname+','+Lname + ','+DRB+','+GDR+','+STRES+','+'MD'
                    recordToWrite = recordToWrite+','+children[x]
                    fileOutput.write(recordToWrite + '\n')
        n = +1

    fileOutput.close()
    fileOutputNotFound.close()

    print('\n--------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------')
    print("Script completed.")
    
##############################################################################


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the 'immunte' function:

```
def immunte(Fname, Lname, DRB, GDR, driver):
    al = []
    # work on  search button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edittesttest']").click()

    # work on 
    lastname = driver.find_element_by_id("LM")
    lastname.clear()
    lastname.send_keys(Lname)

    # work on 
    firstname = driver.find_element_by_id("FN")
    firstname.clear()
    firstname.send_keys(Fname)

    # work on 
    birthdate = driver.find_element_by_id("DRB")
    birthdate.clear()
    birthdate.send_keys(DRB)

    # work on advanced search button to input GDR
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='queryResultsForm']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/input").click()

        # work on GDR selection button
        obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("OSC"))
        if GDR == 'W':
            obj.select_by_index(2)
        elif GDR == 'S':
            obj.select_by_index(1)
        else:
            obj.select_by_index(3)

        # work on search button
        driver.find_element_by_name("cmdFindClient").click()

    

        # two scenarios could emerge as a search result: 1, not found 2, the  found
        if "No were found for the requested search criteria" in driver.find_element_by_id("queryResultsForm").text:
            return al

        if "the found" in driver.find_element_by_id("queryResultsForm").text:

            # work on button
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//*[@id='queryResultsForm']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/label").click()

            # work on pt button
            driver.find_element_by_id("redirect1").click()

            # work on getting rid of opt out  - header
            header = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("large")[1].text

            if "Access Restricted" in header:
                print(Fname+' '+Lname+' '+" Opt out")
                return al

            if "Information" in header:
                # find the first line
                first = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "//*[@id='container']/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]"
                ).text
                
                if (first == None):
                    return al
                
                even = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("evenRow")
                odd = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("oddRow")
                o = []
                e = []

                for value in odd:
                    o.append(value.text)
                for value in even:
                    e.append(value.text)

                length = len(o)
                i = 0
                al = []

                # merge odd and even row together and remove the row marked with complete
                while i < length:
                    al.append(e[i])
                    al.append(o[i])
                    i = i+1

                # parse each row of information with a comma, add group name for row that are without one
                for x in range(len(al)):
                    if is_date(al[x][1:10]):
                        al[x] = al[x].replace(' ', ',')
                        al[x] = al[x].replace(',of,', ' of ')
                        al[x] = group + ',' + al[x][2:]

                    else:
                        al[x] = al[x].replace(' ', ',')
                        al[x] = al[x].replace(',of,', ' of ')
                        g = al[x].split(',', 1)
                        group = g[0]
                        
        # work on returning to home page
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='headerMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    except WebDriverException:
        pass
    
    return  al
```

Comment: Thanks, that got the lookups working however I think this is failing here as the not found file is getting populated
 #
 children = immunte(Fname, Lname, DRB, GDR, driver)

        if children == []:
            not_found += 1
            recordToWrite = MeasYr+','+MIDSK+','+MEMID+',' + Fname + \
                ','+Lname + ',' + ' ' + ','+DRB+','+GDR+','+STRES+','+'MD'
            fileOutputNotFound.write(recordToWrite + '\n')
 #